# ejecutando una aplicacion android creada con ionic el navegar se cierra : error " Cannot read property '_privateInitialize' of undefined"

Tags: android, angular, google-maps, ionic4

Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property '_privateInitialize' of undefined ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property '_privateInitialize' of undefined
    at Map. (Map.js:1350)
    at commandQueueExecutor.js:63
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills-es5.js:9910)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (polyfills-es5.js:9669)
    at polyfills-es5.js:10429
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills-es5.js:9942)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills-es5.js:9714)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills-es5.js:10120) TypeError: Cannot read property '_privateInitialize' of undefined
    at Map. (http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Map.js:1350:11)
    at http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/commandQueueExecutor.js:63:21
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost/polyfills-es5.js:9910:26)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost/polyfills-es5.js:9669:43)
    at http://localhost/polyfills-es5.js:10429:34
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost/polyfills-es5.js:9942:31)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost/polyfills-es5.js:9714:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost/polyfills-es5.js:10120:35)

Sale conectando el movil a pc y mirando la consola en chrome, he mirado varias cosas( version sdk,ionic-native/google-maps/ngx) y nada , si alguien se le ocurre algo se agradece

```
    loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map', {
        'controls': {
            'compass': true,
            'myLocationButton': true,
            'indoorPicker': true,
            'zoom': true, // Only for Android
            'mapToolbar': true   // currently Android only
        },
        'camera': {
            'target': {
                'lat': 40.0000000,
                'lng': -4.0000000
            },
            'zoom': 6,
            'tilt': 30
        },
        'gestures': {
            'scroll': true,
            'tilt': true,
            'rotate': true,
            'zoom': true
        }
    });

    this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
        if (this.chargingStationSelected != null && this.chargingStationSelected.id != undefined) {
            this.restoreMarkerIcon(this.chargingStationSelected.id);
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: Agrega como tratas de cargar el mapa por favor.

Comment: el error venia, por la animación, del market, cuando se quita funciona correctamente sin errores